# Why is gnome-control-center trying to access a gsettings key that doesn't exist?

Tags: laptop, battery, gnome, kali-linux

I am using GNOME Shell 3.38.6 on Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 2021.3.  I've recently started having an odd problem with `gnome-control-center`.  The program completely crashes if I try to access the **Power** tab, and will not open again unless I change the `dconf` value so it opens on a different tab.

Running `gnome-control-center` from the terminal gives this output:

```
┌──(curtice㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gnome-control-center 

(gnome-control-center:6885): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 11:40:47.120: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power' does not contain a key named 'power-saver-profile-on-low-battery'
zsh: trace trap  gnome-control-center
```

It seems it's trying to access a key that doesn't exist.  So I checked the schema just to be sure:

```
┌──(curtice㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
idle-dim
sleep-inactive-battery-type
idle-brightness
ambient-enabled
sleep-inactive-ac-type
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
power-button-action
```

Sure enough, `power-saver-profile-on-low-battery` is not listed.  Is there a way to either install this key from somewhere, or make it stop trying to reference this key?

--

Note:

I'm not sure if this might be related, but I noticed this issue began shortly after using the following commands: `sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw` and `sudo systemctl enable tlp`.  I was trying to figure out how to get my battery to stop draining so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you somehow installed a much newer version of gnome-control-center – power profiles were added in a very recent release, either in 40.x or 41.0, I don't recall at the moment. However, you did not upgrade the rest of the system (gnome-settings-daemon and/or gsettings-desktop-schemas).

Comment: Just ran `sudo apt update`, and it said that all packages were up to date.  Running `apt-cache policy gnome-control-center` shows that the only available version of the package is `1:41.0-2`.  I only have one repository in `sources.list`: the main kali-rolling repository from kali.org.  Could there be a way to fix this using the current versions of the packages?